# How to manually trigger an update of /etc/hosts in WSL?

Tags: hosts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I start the first WSL terminal (ubuntu 20.04 bash in my case), WSL generates the `/etc/hosts` file based on the host file of my windows system `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

If I now change the `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, e.g. add some entries, the `/etc/hosts` in my WSL is not updated. Even if I close all WSL terminals and open a new one. Only reboot of my windows system helps.

Is there a way I can manually trigger the update of the `/etc/hosts` so that I do not have to reboot?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As long as this

```
[network]
generateHosts = true
generateResolvConf = true
```

is in your `/etc/wsl.conf` a restart of the LxssManager* services should do the trick.

Beware: Restarting Lxss* will terminate *all* your running WSL Instances.

```
Restart-Service LxssManager*
```

Comment: It works. I just had to execute `Restart-Service LxssManager*` in a power shell that was started with admin rights.

Comment: It also worked for my although I don't have those entries in `wsl.conf`

Comment: Beware that restarting this service will terminate all your active WSL instances.